# Add type in animated feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I wish to create a feature where the letters are typed in between a sentence as it is done in this [page](http://www.google.com/docs/about/) .

In the above link there is a sentence inside the banner that says

```
Create meaningful documents 
Create persuasive documents  
Create impactful documents
```

If you notice, the 2nd word is changing while the first and the third word remains the same, can anyone please tell how this animated feature can be achieved

Comment: With code. I will say that this is beyond what CSS can do realistically.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol any alternative that you can suggest

Comment: Can be done with CSS but only if all words (that appear in the middle) are of same length (or atleast close enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using javascript. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/kvvxu33v/) is a plugin that i made that types letters using `setInterval()` function.

Original Demo:

```js
typer = function(e, s, d, t) {
  var eI = 0;
  var speed = s;
  var delay = d;
  var eLength = t.length;
  var z = 1;

  function loop() {
    var p = $("<div class='azy-typer-container azy-typer-done'></div>");
    var c_t = $("<span class='azy-typer-element'></span>")
    var c_b = $("<span class='azy-typer-blinker'>|</span>");
    $(".azy-typer-blinker").remove();
    p.append(c_t).append(c_b);
    $(e).append(p);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      c_t.text(t[eI].substring(0, z));
      if (z + 1 > t[eI].length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        eI = eI + 1;
        if (eI + 1 <= t.length) {
          z = 0;
          setTimeout(loop, d);
        }
      } else {
        z = z + 1;
      }
    }, s)
  }
  loop();
}
new typer(".container", 100, 1000, ["Hi there!", "This is a typer demo ", "What do you think about this ?"]);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
span {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.azy-typer-blinker {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    color: crimson;
  }
  50% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    color: crimson;
  }
}
.azy-typer-done {
  margin-left: 24px;
}
.azy-typer-done:before {
  content: ">>";
  color: lightgreen;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

You can do some changes to make this code work as you need

```js
typer = function(e, s, d, t) {
  var eI = 0;
  var speed = s;
  var delay = d;
  var eLength = t.length;
  var z = 1;

  function loop() {
    var p = $("<div class='azy-typer-container'></div>");
    var c_t = $("<span class='azy-typer-element'></span>")
    var c_b = $("<span class='azy-typer-blinker'>|</span>");
    $(".azy-typer-blinker").remove();
    p.append(c_t).append(c_b);
    $(e).append(p);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      c_t.text(t[eI].substring(0, z));
      if (z + 1 > t[eI].length) {
        p.addClass("azy-typer-done");
        clearInterval(interval);
        eI = eI + 1;
        if (eI + 1 <= t.length) {
          z = 0;
          setTimeout(loop, d);
        } else {
          eI = 0;
          z = 0;
          setTimeout(loop, d);
        }
      } else {
        z = z + 1;
      }
    }, s)
  }
  loop();
}
new typer(".container", 100, 1000, ["Hi there!", "This is a typer demo ", "What do you think about this ?"]);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
span {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.azy-typer-blinker {
  color: maroon;
}
.azy-typer-container {
  display: inline;
}
.azy-typer-done {
  display: none;
}
.static {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="static">Static </span>
</div>
```

The function takes four arguments

1. The element to which the text is to be appended
2. The typing speed
3. The delay for the next item to appear
4. The text (should be an array)